# Create instructions to configure emergency messages to send to terminal of the root user

Tags: linux, stderr

I'm a Linux student and I have been asked to create Instructions to configure emergency messages to be sent to the terminal of the root user (reporting system errors).

How could I send error messages to the terminal of the root user?

Using stderr redirection?